# How can I properly take in account the order returns in my aggregate SQL queries?

Tags: sql-server, filter, relational-database, aggregate-functions

I have a table like the one shown below.

My goal is to develop a query that returns the one time shoppers and the repeat shoppers, and their respective aggregate total for the total dollars spend and the average dollar spent (per customer).

However, I am struggling on how to factor in the returns.

I want to know how I could properly take in account the fact that some orders were returns, therefore I would not count them as a second order from the customer.

I developed the query below but that would count an order and its return as two and that is not what I need (like Customer 1 would be counted as a two time purchaser even though he buys once and then returns).

Please see the query below that I used to calculate the repeat purchaser (more than one time).

[image]

```
select 
    count(*) as number_of_repeat_shoppers, 
    sum(total) as total_revenue_from_repeat_shoppers ,
    avg(total) as average_revenue_from_repeat_shopper
from 
    (Select customer_id, sum(total_cost) as total
     from ORDERS
     group by customer_id
     having count(DATE) > 1)
```

Comment: @Icasucci; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for total shop info :

```
With RepeatedShoppers (
    select -- Filter Repeated Shoppers List
        customer_id
    from ORDERS
    where Quantity <> -1
    group by customer_id
    having count(DATE) > 1
)
select -- Total Info of Orders [Filtered Shoppers]
    count(DATE) as number_of_repeat_shoppers,
    sum(total_cost) as total_revenue_from_repeat_shoppers ,
    avg(total_cost) as average_revenue_from_repeat_shopper
from ORDERS
where Quantity <> -1 and customer_id in (Select customer_id from RepeatedShoppers)
```

And, if you want shop info per shopper :

```
select -- Repeated Shoppers Info
    customer_id,
    count(DATE) as number_of_shop_of_this_shopper,
    sum(total_cost) as total_revenue_from_this_shopper,
    avg(total_cost) as average_revenue_from_this_shopper
from ORDERS
where Quantity <> -1
group by customer_id
having count(DATE) > 1
```